# Java SimpleDateFormat -- input and output is different

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I get the date string --"2012-04-19 20:51:06". Then I get the milli time by SimpleDateFormat.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date d=sdf.parse("2012-04-19 20:51:06");
    long milliTime=d.getTime()
```

Then the milliTime is 1334839866000L

However when I convert milliTime to date format String. The result is "2012-04-19 08:51:06"

```
    long time = 1334839866000L;
    Date date = new Date(time);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    String t = sdf.format(date);
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Try using HH for the hour component rather than hh.

Comment: +1. The difference being 24-hours format (HH) versus am/pm (hh).

Comment: But shouldn't the one format (hh?) throw an exception, when fed with the wrong input (20)?

Comment: @user unknown: I haven't done any testing, but the Java Doc says: By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).